# is this a correct way to analyze a graph?

Tags: java, algorithm, analysis, dijkstra

Hi guys I need help with analyzing a graph , I have implemented Dijkstra algorithm but i'm not sure about my analysis.
is this a correct way to analyze a graph ?

my analysis are in the comments.

```
public class Dijkstra {

    for (int i = 0; i < distance.length; i++)//O(v^2)
    {
        visited[i] = 0; 
        preD[i] = 0;

        for (int j = 0; j < distance.length; j++)
        {
            matrix[i][j] = scan.nextInt(); 
            if (matrix[i][j]==0)
                matrix[i][j] = 999; 
        }
    }


    for (int counter = 0; counter < n; counter++)//O(V^2) 
    {
        min = 999;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            if (min > distance[i] && visited[i]!=1) 
            {
                min = distance[i];
                nextNode = i;
            }
        } 




        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)//O(E) 
        {
            if (visited[i]!=1)
            {
                if (min+matrix[nextNode][i] < distance[i])
                {
                    distance[i] = min+matrix[nextNode][i]; 
                    preD[i] = nextNode;
                }

            }

        }

    }//finally Dijkstra takes O(v^2) 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the classical implementation of the djikstra algorithm, and it is easy to notice that the nested loop determines the complexity. So yes, you are correct. There is a better version that uses a prioritized data structure for getting the next closest node,with which the complexity drops to `O(n * log n)`.